# Mongoose update only a few properties from object of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

here is my schema

```
{
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    accountId: { type: String, required: true },
    orders: { type: Object, required: true },
}
```

I want to be able to update multiple of those orders without overwriting anything from the orders I did not specify.

Say I currently have this

```
"orders": {
    "5520": {
        "productId": "uuidv4 string",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    "8123": {
        "productId": "uuidv4 string",
        "quantity": 5
    },
    "8219": {
        "productId": "uuidv4 string",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    "10113": {
        "productId": "uuidv4 string",
        "quantity": 2
    },
}
```

If I pass

```
"orders": {
    "8123": {
        "productId": "uuidv4 string",
        "quantity": 50
    },
    "10113": {
        "productId": "uuidv4 string",
        "quantity": 50
    },
}
```

I would like 5520 and 8219 to remain the same, and also, in case 8123 and 10113 have other properties, I would like them to also remain the same and only update whatever I passed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
let document in Db as

> 

```
{ 
>     "_id" : 1, 
>     "domainName" : "abc.com", 
>     "link" : "https://example.com", 
>     "orders" : {
>         "5520" : {
>             "productId" : "uuidv4 string", 
>             "quantity" : 1.0
>         }, 
>         "8123" : {
>             "productId" : "uuidv4 string", 
>             "quantity" : NumberInt(10)
>         }, 
>         "8219" : {
>             "productId" : "uuidv4 string", 
>             "quantity" : 1.0
>         }, 
>         "10113" : {
>             "productId" : "uuidv4 string", 
>             "quantity" : NumberInt(10)
>         }
>     } }

 let data = {
        "orders": {
            "8123": {
                "productId": "uuidv4 string",
                "quantity": 150
            },
            "10113": {
                "productId": "uuidv4 string",
                "quantity": 150
            },
        }
    }
    let x = data.orders;
    let query = {}
    for (var prop in x) {
        let str = `orders.${prop}`
        query[str] = x[prop]
    }
    var updateQuery = { $set: query }
    await db1.findOneAndUpdate({ id: 1, }, updateQuery);
```